# Read a Line and Fetch the value of a particular word in Java

Tags: java

I have file which I read line by line in java.

Below is the content of the file 

`My File contains the following characters (persons, indicated by name)

There are three characters in this line Jack = 10 Jill = 11 Jhon = 12

There are two characters in the line Jack = 14 Melissa = 15`

I have to search line by line for 'Jack' and I have to fetch his value 10 (in first line) and 14 (in second line) and pass it to another variable. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. I assume you know how to read file line by line, that's the draft of what you should do for every line.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*Jack)\\s*=\\s*(\\d+)(.*)");
    String testString = " Jack =154, Jill = 111";

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
     }
```

These are the essentials you should know to understand what's going on: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/